# Merging Tabulate Area Results by County using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst

I'm working in ArcGIS Pro v2.4 with all extensions. I have a bunch of tables that are the result of running the Tabulate Area tool on a series of raster map tiles to calculate land cover by county in the United States. The issue I am running into is that some counties are covered by two or more different map tiles, so some tables have the partial results for the part of the county that was covered by the map tile.

I thought I'd be able to just run the Merge tool and use field mapping to apply the Sum merge rule on the value fields that need to be added together, like this:
[image]

Instead, I'm getting duplicate records in the table, like this:
[image]

Any idea what I might be doing wrong, or if there's a different tool/process I should be using instead?

Comment: I'm guessing your FIPS field is remaining Unique during the merge process? Try merging as normal then run your data through the summary statistics tool grouping by FIPS and summing your fields? Not sure if that is the logic you are looking for?

Comment: @Hornbydd that did the trick - thanks!